# Meaning of the word 'tight'

Tags: meaning, slang

What's the meaning of “tight” in the following sentence?

> This is the least tight thing that's ever happened for me.

Comment: You should provide some more context; might it be from [this blog post](http://lb-for-lb.blogspot.com/2010/07/this-is-least-tight-thing-thats-ever.html)? Anyway, it’s not a meaning I've heard or read before…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tight means cool while being safe in this sentence.

Another form of this sentence could be "This is the closest to death in my life .".

Comment: I know this word means here. My English friend told me. Could you give me a link to the meaning in online dict?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes *a tight thing* means:

- dangerous : something that the speaker was so lucky to escape from it
- a difficult situation

But I don't have any idea that what happened to that person!

Comment: Apart from the idiom “a tight corner”, do you have examples of *tight* having the meanings you list?

Comment: Rayle said: “It was so close, and sort of a tight thing there was nowhere easy to run. So most of the crowd got it. People that were there were just sitting ducks. I don’t think he was even aiming. He was just firing at whatever.”

After a few moments the shooter tried to flee but was tackled and subsequently apprehended.

Comment: "We're in a tight spot!" -Everett, from O Brother Where Art Thou?

Answer (score 0):

It may have a meaning from jazz. Here is some search on 'tight jazz composition':
Grammy Award For Best Original Jazz Composition on WN Network delivers the ... and are notable for the tight renditions of highly difficult jazz fusion